# Unable to install Components in Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am working with Xamarin Android, and in the past couple of days have found that I am unable to install components into projects.

I am on Visual Studio 15.3.0 (2017), and basically whenever I add a component, everything looks fine until I close the project and re-open.

Before:

[image: Everything looks fine, before closing project]

After:

[image: Nothing works, after re-opening project]

Things I have tried:

1. Updating Visual Studio
2. Reinstalling Visual Studio
3. Deleting everything *Xamarin* related in C:\Users{Me}\AppData\Local

I have lost two full days of work because of this and am getting a bit desperate, at this point I'm considering reinstalling Windows.

Can anybody provide any insight on why this is happening?

Regards

Comment: In my opinion, you should use NuGet as these packages are listed there. The component is simply a wrapper to the NuGet packages anyway. Ensure you update to the latest `Xamarin.Build.Download` package as well.

Comment: I'm having the same issues through Nuget as well, really weird

Comment: What version of Java are you running? Later Xamarin versions / updates require Java 8 at least.

Comment: Java 8, I have the most recent Android development tools installed too.